# Muliple Websphere Application Servers attached to a single Websphere MQ Failing

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

**Issue:**
Having multiple consumer applications active specification attached to a single MQ on distributed VM servers is causing a null payload in a MQ Message. 
Note: See notes at the bottom. No issue with mq.

**Details:**
I have 3 Websphere applications deployed across 2 VM servers. 1 application is a publisher and the other 2 applications are consumers attached to a single MQ Manager, and MQ. 
2 consumer applications are pulling off the messages and processing them. The consumer application on the separate server receives a null payload. I have confirmed that its seems to be an issue having multiple application server instances attached to MQ. Confirmed by deploying the publisher on server 2 with consumer 2, then consumer 1 fails.

**Question:**
Has anyone tried attaching multiple MDB applications deployed on separate server instances bind to one Queue Manager and one MQ?

**Specifications:**

Websphere 7, EJB 3.0 MDB's,Transactions turned off,Queue in a queue installed on another machine.

**Goal:**

Distributed computing, scaling up against large number of messages.

I'm thinking this is a configuration issue but not 100% sure where to look. I had read that you could use MQLink, but I don't see why I would need to use service bus integration.

**Supporting Doucmentation:** 
[MQ Link][1

UPDATE: I fixed the problem and it was a related to a combination of class loader issue with a duplicate classes. See Solution Notes below I added.

EDIT HISTORY:
- Clarified specifications, clarified question and added overall goal.
- reference notes to solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This specific problem was caused by a code issue and the combination of class loading being set to "Parent First" in the Websphere console. On one node it would work and the other nodes in a cluster would fail, I think this was caused by the "Parent First" setting.

More important, in terms of my configuration in a cluster binding multiple active specifications to a single MQ to provide distributed computing is a correct solution.

However "points" due go to "nitgeek" solution references above if you are looking for a extremely high volume solution. Its important to understand that a single MQ can have a very high depth and takes a lot to fully utilize one.  My current configuration is a good starting point for quick configuration and distributed processing using Multiple MDB's.

Answer (score 1):

> Has anyone tried attaching multiple MDB applications deployed on
>   separate server instances bind to one Local MQ?

Multiple MDB applications deployed on separate servers, connecting to one Queue Manager(but different queue) is a normal scenario and we have it everywhere and all applications work fine.

But, I suspect what you are doing is: Multiple MDB applications deployed on separate servers, connecting to one Queue Manager and **listening to the same queue**.

In this case one message will be received by one consumer only.

You need to create separate queue for each application and create subscriptions for each for the topic being published by your publisher.

> **Addition:**

I suspect, for load balancing the problem you may be facing is that, when your first application gets the message, it doesn't issue a commit. So, there will be an uncommited message in the queue, which may be stopping your other application from getting message from the queue. When your first application finishes its processing, it issues a commit, but then again it is ready to pick the message and hence it again issues a get.

In my architecture, we have implemented load balancing using multiple queue managers like below:

You create 3 queue managers, say **GatewayQM**, **App1QM** and **App2QM**.

Keep the three queue managers in the same cluster.

Create an alias queue(shared in cluster) in **GatewayQM** and ask your putting app to put message in the gateway queue.

Now create one local cluster queue in each of App1QM and App2QM. Read from these queues via your applications App1 and App2 respectively.

This implementation provides you better security and serves a perfect load balancer.

Comment: No I want to be listening to the same queue. Its a distributed computing solution. You define for your MDB the max number of sessions you want to pull off for your MDB. If you have 5000 messages in the queues and you want 15 threads for each deployed MDB to process at once ( based on performance and hardware ) , each MDB will pull his max number and process them. I think I have it figured out it now, will post solution once I confirm.

Comment: Ok, so it's load balancing you are talking about. If two processes are listening to the same queue, then definitely messages will be divided among the processes. What I meant in my reply is that same message can't go to both. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: Ya the load balancing is occurring, its just the message is being corrupted when picked up by secondary server. Can commiting affect other consumer end? MQ is just a broker with a message, once the publisher publishes that message it shouldn't affect consumer side. Your solution would work, basically having a gateway but to avoid the overkill of scaling by queue manager group. You could add local queue references in the app server which act as a proxy to the physical queue. That or a MQ link which does the router but requires more infrastructure.

Comment: Can you clarify why you chose to scale by entire queue manager as opposed to using local queue as a proxy to the remote queue or maybe the MQlink mentioned in IBM doc that does the routing? Thanks for your input. This is good insight I think for other people.

Comment: Our traffic is too much that one machine can't handle it. We have different queue managers on different servers.

Comment: Have you ever tried setting up a SI Bus as part of the MQLink? Before implementing a higher availability solution with the cluster gateway. One thing that needs to occur it appears is you need to use a MQLink over a Service Bus Integration. Have you set one up nitgeek? Did you have any trouble with your active specifications not being able to pick up messages off the Service Bus?

Comment: @haju No we didn't.As the matter of fact, we don't even use WAS. We have, lots of main frame based applications and few packaged products like SAP, Red-praire, JDA etc used to handle business of a huge retailer.